# JS/CSS Combo - getting 3D image wrap effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to get the 3D wrap effect for images on my website. A 3D wrap is something like the one in this [image](https://s32.postimg.org/6vpzhkl6t/blue_orange_black_diamond_3d_monogram_initial_ga.jpg).

The effect I require is exactly as in the image.

The following is the pure CSS I'm using to implement this at the moment.

```
.gallery-wrap{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px black !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px black !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px 0px black !important;
  }
  .gallery-wrap img{
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg) translateX(7.5%) translateY(30px);
    margin-bottom: 5em !important;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 7px -1px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 7px -1px black;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 7px -1px black;
  }
  .gallery-wrap div:after{
    content: '';
    width: 5%;
    height: 96%;
    background-image: url('<url of the same image the is to be wrapped>');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    transform: perspective(250px) rotateY(-55deg) translateY(7px) translateX(-10px);
    left: 0px;
    background-size: 10% 750%;
    background-position-x: 0%;
  }
```

The code works, but the problem is it doesn't work for all the images. An image with more height than width will result in the above code.

I would be interested in a JS algorithm or existing (preferably free) library which does this. The algorithm should capture width and height of the `img` element and then render `transform` values for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The code is as follows

```
.gallery-wrap{
    perspective: 1000px;  //required to get the correct 3D depth
}
.gallery-wrap div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 36px;
    height: 100%;
    background: inherit;
    background-size: cover, cover;
    background-position: left; //This and the next 2 lines are for left edge. Change bottom/top/right accordingly
    transform: rotateY(90deg); // Y is the Axis of rotation. Change accordingly. 90deg will flip (mirror) the image
    transform-origin: left; // Which side to be flipped
}
.gallery-wrap div {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("<image_link>"); // Just to add a gradient effect to the farther side
    background-size: 0, cover;  //To get the gradient effect
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    margin: 10% auto; // This and the next line 2 line are dimension adjustments
    width: 80%;
    transform: rotateY(37.5deg); // This is for the main image rotation
    transform-origin: center; // This is for point of origin of the transform. Use center for the best effect;
}
```

The image has to be used as the background image.

Structure of the elements - `.gallery-wrap > div`

Credits to the original source - [TheCodePlayer](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/3d-thumbnail-image-hover-effect)